# How to set a custom header in AV player in iOS

Tags: ios, avplayer

We are using AVplayer on iOS and we have a requirement to pass a custom value in header of every request that the player sends (for both manifest and TS segments). We saw this is possible by using a reverse proxy but this is not acceptable solution for our client.

Is there any way we can pass a custom value in any existing / new header to AVPlayer is ios from app ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any solution?